# Extract text that follows a specific word/s in R

Tags: r

Say I have a string that reads:

"database service crashed due to monkeys in the circuit board and this is a serious problem."

How can I extract the, say, 5 words that follow the phrase 'due to'

So I would get this:

monkeys in the circuit board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this tinkered way?

```
v <- "database service crashed due to monkeys in the circuit board and this is a serious problem."
unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(v, "due to"))[2], " "))[2:6]
[1] "monkeys" "in"      "the"     "circuit" "board"
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear whether you want a single string as output or a string for each word but assuming you want a single string if `x` is the input string then this `sub` will do it:

```
s <- sub(".*due to ((\\w+ ){4}\\w+).*", "\\1", x)
```

giving:

```
> s
[1] "monkeys in the circuit board"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
.*due to ((\w+ ){4}\w+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/T0tFMYL1ybVIqFdP)

If you want separate words then

```
strsplit(s, " ")[[1]]
```

giving:

```
[1] "monkeys" "in"      "the"     "circuit" "board"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.  It has the advantage over RStudent's of extracting the five important words that follow "due to", but it creates an odd stemming result.  I suspect that can be solved too.  The two lines could be combined of course.

```
text <- "database service crashed due to monkeys in the circuit board and this is a serious problem." 
text.short <- unlist(str_split(text, "due to"))
five <- str_extract_all(text.short[2], "(\\w){5}")

[1] "monke" "circu" "board" "serio" "probl"
```

Comment: Also good. Interesting use of extracting only the important words.