# Extracting specific word followed by another in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a description of open positions. I want to take grade out of them and post it in a column adjacent. It can be done by fetching word next to "Grade:" in the text description

**Simulation**

```
  structure(list(description = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Grade: L3 Position title bla bla bla", 
"Head of xxxxxxxx Grade: L5 Last Date to Apply: 22nd July 2019"
), class = "factor"), division = structure(2:1, .Label = c("ABC", 
"XYZ"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Requested Result

```
Description     Division     Grade
sdsdsdsd         XYZ          L5
asdasdsadas      ABC          L3
```

I found this solution, it can get the word out, but not put it in column.

[Extract text that follows a specific word/s in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975296/extract-text-that-follows-a-specific-word-s-in-r)

Comment: *I found this solution, it can get the word out but not put in column* so your problem is not to get the words but only to assign the results?

Comment: Yes, however would appreciate a different and more efficient solution as well.

Comment: `df$Grade <- sub(".+(?<=Grade: )(.{2}).+", "\\1", df$description, perl=TRUE)`?

Comment: Maybe you can share how exactly you get the words. Also, the data you provide has class factor for descripton which does not work with strplit (or does it?)

Comment: @ronakshah, can we make it work for cases where `Grade: L3` and with whitespace `Grade : L3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28975296/4137985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sub` and extract a word after `"Grade"` with 0 or more whitespace before and after `:`

```
sub(".*Grade\\s*:\\s*(\\w+).*", "\\1", df$description)
#[1] "L5" "L3"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the stringr package like this:

```
library(stringr)
df[,"Grade"] <- sub("Grade: ", "", str_extract(df$description, "Grade: [^ ]+"))
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(description = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Grade: L3 Position title bla bla bla", 
                                                       "Head of xxxxxxxx Grade: L5 Last Date to Apply: 22nd July 2019"
), class = "factor"), division = structure(2:1, .Label = c("ABC", 
                                                           "XYZ"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                           -2L))
```

**EDIT:**
I have just seen that there are far better answers inside the comments. So better use one of them since they do not rely on an extra package.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for solution, this is getting me more than just L3 and L5 in my original dataset in `df$Grade`

Comment: then please share one row of your original dataset.

Comment: I figure the problem is the white space i.e. in some cases there is `Grade: L3` in others, it is `Grade : L3`

Comment: try: `df[,"Grade"] <- sub("Grade\\s*: ", "", str_extract(df$description, "Grade\\s*: [^ ]+"))`